# Communicating Via Serial1 on Arduino Mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, xbee, softwareserial

Apologies if this a relatively simple question, but I am rather new to Arduino's and cannot seem to find any concise information on the topic.
This is my XBee, mounted on a shield and placed onto a MEGA 2560. I want to leave Serial for USB debugging and use the Serial1 for XBee communication.
[image]

Just to confirm, the two XBee's do communicate if I use SoftwareSerial.   This is the code that works using SoftwareSerial:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// XBee's DOUT (TX) is connected to pin 10 (Arduino's Software RX)
// XBee's DIN (RX) is connected to pin 11 (Arduino's Software TX)
SoftwareSerial serial1(10, 11); // RX, TX
boolean nextLine = false;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  serial1.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() 
{
   while(serial1.available()){ // there is data being sent from the xBee
    char read = char(serial1.read());
    if(read == 'A'){
      //Where ~ is the EOT character
      serial1.write("55.134~");
    }
  }
}
```

How do I communicate using Serial1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the headers on the Mega, you'll notice that one of them has labels of "RX1" and "TX1" through "RX3" and "TX3". You'll also notice that the XBee shield *does not* connect to that header, therefore you *cannot* use `Serial1` through `Serial3` with the shield. Either switch to a breakout board that you can connect manually or stick to software serial.

Comment: Or pop off the jumpers on the shield and use a couple of jumper wires to connect the right pins of that header to the RX1 and TX1 pins on the Mega.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will do as Majenko has suggested and connect it through to Serial1 with some wires.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MultiSerialMega) on the Arduino site, but in short, you'd use the Serial1 (or -2 or -3) object the same way you use the Serial object:

```
Serial1.begin(9600);
if( Serial1.available() ){ ... }
```

etc.